# Regular Expression to get chunk of Alpha characters around a forward slash (JAVA)

Tags: java, regex

I'm not really good at regular expressions so I need some help here.

I have a long string of garbled characters (special and alpha numeric); however somewhere in the middle I have a chunk that I'm interested in where it has two sets of words separated by a forward slash like:

$234207YELLOW/GREEN$M4/ZlAVadvae1bUAoIfaEbEAZ4HdBHr2ftv+3tIo+yw==

And I'm interested in the YELLOW/GREEN part of the whole thing; and the part that I'm interested in can be anywhere in the string so I can't rely on an index :(

Can you help me find the regex that I can use in my Java code to get this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "word":

```
[a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]+
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not 100% sure if that is what you want but it looks like you need to find words that are separated by `/` so maybe this will help a little

```
String s="$234207YELLOW/GREEN$M4/ZlAVadvae1bUAoIfaEbEAZ4HdBHr2ftv+3tIo+yw==";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]+");
Matcher m=p.matcher(s);
if(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

output: `YELLOW/GREEN`

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking words to be just letters (regardless of case) you can use what @TimK or @Pshemo suggested: 
 `"[a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]+"`

However, if the words are all caps you could simplify it more to be
 `"[A-Z]+/[A-Z]+"`

or if you have a list of known words you could use 
`"(RED|YELLOW|ORANGE|GREEN|BLUE|PURPLE)/(RED|YELLOW|ORANGE|GREEN|BLUE|PURPLE)"`

I tend to use this cheat sheet a lot when working with regex
http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html